# Write a function to return the first element to appear an odd number of times in a string

Tags: python

I would like to write a function that would return the first element that appears odd of times in a string.

I am aware that there is code to return an element an odd number of times and I tried to apply it to a string, but to not much success:

```
def getOddOccurrence(arr, arr_size): 
    for i in range(0,arr_size): 
        count = 0
        for j in range(0, arr_size): 
            if arr[i] == arr[j]: 
                count+=1
              
        if (count % 2 != 0): 
            return arr[i] 
          
    return -1
```

driver code:

```
arr = ["Hello world!"] 
n = len(arr) 
print(getOddOccurrence(arr, n))
# Output: "Hello world!
```

If the given string `"Hello world!"`, how would I return the first element that appears an odd number of times?

Comment: odd number of times is confusing. Can you share what's your desired output for `"Hello world!"`?

Comment: First, why are you passing a list if you just want to check a single string? Currently, you aren't comparing any characters of that string, only elements in the list

Comment: `"Hello World" -> "H"`  `"llo World" -> "l"`
Is that the output you expect?

Comment: When you run both the loops from 0 to n, you are wrongly counting the element that appear at the same index.

Comment: Yes I would expect H in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there was some discussion to provide an optimized solution, here it is:
This build's on @SowjanyaRBhat 's code and optimizes it. Pretty much what @OneCriketeer mentioned.

**Space Complexity : O(N)**
**Time Complexity : O(N)**

**Approach 1**: without `collections.Counter`

```
from collections import defaultdict


def getOddOccurrence(myString):
    count = defaultdict(int)
    for letter in myString:
        count[letter] += 1
    for letter in myString:
        if count[letter] % 2 != 0:
            return letter
```

**Approach 2**: with `collections.Counter`

(check the cool one-liner in @Alain.T's answer)

```
from collections import Counter


def getOddOccurrence(myString):
    count = Counter(myString)
    for letter in myString:
        if count[letter] % 2 != 0:
            return letter


# driver code
myString = "llo world!"
print(getOddOccurrence(myString))

# Output: "l"
```

Comment: First 3 lines of the function can be replaced with `count = collections.Counter(myString)`...

Comment: Great thank you! Just so I understand this correctly, the use of the dictionary function is like hashing? Then it loops back round to find the first odd occurring letter? Thank you all for responding so fast - didn't expect that! :)

Comment: Yes. It's a two pass solution. In first loop we use dictionary to maintain count of characters; in second loop we check for first odd-count character.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying - just learnt about hashing today so it's nice seeing it in practice like this :)

Answer (score 0):

Return the first element that is having odd number of occurrences :

```
def getOddOccurrence(myString):
    for letter in myString:
        letter_count = myString.count(letter)
        if letter_count%2 != 0:
            return letter
    return None
      
      
# driver code  
myString = "Hello world!"
print(getOddOccurrence(myString))
```

Output: "H"

Comment: More optimal solution would avoid using `.count` within a loop

Comment: i dont know to do that xD

Comment: Great! Thank you so much! :)

Comment: removed  the second line

Comment: Loop over the string once. Put the character counts into the dictionary. Loop over the string twice, then return the first dict value with an odd count. O(N) solution rather than this O(N^2)

Comment: thats helpful ! thankyou :) i see someone has given that as the answer now.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Counter from collections to get the character count and then just find the first character with an odd count:

```
from collections import Counter
def firstOdd(S):
    return next((c for counts in [Counter(S)] for c in S if counts[c]%2),"")

print(firstOdd("Hello World")) # 'H'

print(firstOdd("bold World Wide Web")) # 'd'
```

Comment: Amazing! I like how it's very concise and you gave two examples! I appreciate it thank you!